# Binding to Business object containg Enum Type as one of the properties

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I've a Class Called "Lead" as below

```
public class Lead
{
   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
   
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
   
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
  
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
  
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LocationString { get; set; }
    public string Communication { get; set; }
  
    public Status Status { get; set; }
  
    public LocationType LocationType { get; set; }
}

public enum Status
{
    Contacted=1,Ceated=2
}

public enum LocationType
{
    City=1,State=2,Country=3
}
```

I've request body as below

```
{
"first_name": "Dixi",          
"last_name": "Payal",          
"mobile": "7412589632",          
"email": "asd@email.com",      
"location_type": "1",        
"location_string":  "India"  
}
```

User will pass string for location type Enum. default model binder throws error for this .
Can any one let me know how to properly check for enum values and binds it to the properties of object

Answer (score 0):

Try to send `"location_type": 1,` as integer. ASP.NET Core 3.1 by default binds enum by its integer value.